# applying regex to xml file in python

Tags: python, regex, xml, python-3.x

I have a python assignment where i have to apply regex operations to XML file.
To be specific i have to extract certain sections in the XML file.For example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<.... some xml sections...>

<keyword:ROW field1="value1">
<field2>=value2</field3>
<field3>=value3</field3>
</keyword:ROW>

<keyword:ROW field4="value4">
<field4>=value4</field4>
<field4>=value4</field4>
</keyword:ROW>
```

In the above code example i have to extract the sections starting with

```
<keyword:ROW"
```

Please tell me how to apply re.compile() to this problem statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parsing XML using regex isn't a good idea because XML data may contain nested structures leading to unexpected results while parsing using regex.

Although for simple cases, you can do a quick and dirty work but in long run you should go for XML parser. Just for your case, you can use this regex,

```
(?s)<keyword:ROW.*?<\/keyword:ROW>
```

To find all occurrences of your `<keyword:ROW` tag

**Explanation:**

- `(?s)` --> Enables . to match newlines which is not by default
- `<keyword:ROW` --> Matches your intended keyword
- `.*?` --> Matches any character after that non-greedily and stops just before `<\/keyword:ROW>`
- `<\/keyword:ROW>` --> Matches the end tag and stops capturing the text

Here is the python code you will need,

```
import re
s = """
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<.... some xml sections...>

<keyword:ROW field1="value1">
<field2>=value2</field3>
<field3>=value3</field3>
</keyword:ROW>

<keyword:ROW field4="value4">
<field4>=value4</field4>
<field4>=value4</field4>
</keyword:ROW>
"""

arr = re.findall(r'(?s)<keyword:ROW.*?<\/keyword:ROW>', s)
print(arr)
```

Which gives following output which is basically your two tags present in your sample xml.

```
['<keyword:ROW field1="value1">\n<field2>=value2</field3>\n<field3>=value3</field3>\n</keyword:ROW>', '<keyword:ROW field4="value4">\n<field4>=value4</field4>\n<field4>=value4</field4>\n</keyword:ROW>']
```

Let me know if you need explanation for anything here.

Comment: Would you recommend me to go for APIs like ETree?

Comment: Yes [ETree](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) is a better option to parse such recursive strutures and you may want to explore [lxml](https://lxml.de/) a third party lib which even provides more features and even [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this**

```
<keyword:ROW\s[\w\W]*?<\/keyword:ROW>
```

> Explanation

- `<keyword:ROW`- Matches `<keyword:ROW`.
- `\s` - Matches space character.
- `[\w\W]*?` - Matches any character zero or more time.(? make it lazy)
- `<\/keyword:ROW>` - Matches `</keyword:ROW>`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/03W43y/1/)

Comment: please share any helpful links which teaches regex in python from basic to advanced for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try the `xml` module?

Eg.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('example.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for item in root.findall('keyword:ROW'):
    field2 = country.find('field2').text
    print field2
```

Refer: https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html